# Total number of pages including frontmatter and backmatter

Tags: xetex, book-design, page

Is there any way to get total number of pages in the document.
I am typesetting a book and first page where I write publication info needs to include total number of the pages in the book. I wonder if it is possible to do automatically.

Comment: Depends on the documentclass you are using...

Comment: I use extbook class with B5 page type.

Comment: You might want to have a closer look to the lastpage package (ie the abstract of the) documentation found here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage/lastpage.pdf